# (R) for loop for a data frame not working

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, for-loop

I am trying to create a data frame using a for-loop, since I want to update the rows in the data frame with a new element on each iteration. However, only the last value is printed into the data frame.

I have tried to read different files into a data frame, and then use 'cbind' to match the entry-number of the data file to the number of, in this case, complete cases in a file. The code works for a single entry, but I cannot get the for loop to add all the different rows together; it seems to copy the second iteration over the first, and so on.

### complete cases

```
complete <- function(directory, id) {

    fileList <- dir(directory, full.names = TRUE);
    frame <- data.frame();

    for (i in seq_along(id)) {

        data <- complete.cases(read_csv(fileList[i]));
        frame <- cbind(i, sum(data));
    }

}
```

As such, I want to obtain a data frame that lists the different files in the directory specified, along with the number of complete cases. Can you tell me what I am doing wrong in this for-loop?

Answer (score 1):

Since you always overwrite your dataframe `frame` in your loop, you need to `cbind` it too.

```
complete <- function(directory, id) {

    fileList <- dir(directory, full.names = TRUE);
    frame <- data.frame();

    for (i in seq_along(id)) {

        data <- complete.cases(read_csv(fileList[i]));
        frame <- cbind(frame, i, sum(data));
    }

}
```

otherwise your `frame` gets set every new iteration. So if you want to add it to your `frame`, you have to give the `frame` also as input

Comment: Hi, thanks, this worked. However, adding " i " to the cbind command does not work. The resulting output is not the ID sequence as indexes of the rows, but is simply the index of the data frame itself. E.g. when I input complete(directory, 5:20), the output is a list numbered from 1 to 16. How can I solve this to have the rows correspond to the correct identifier?

Comment: @user2892481 i'm sorry i don't understand what exactly you want to achieve. The i in your code is of course your variable from the loop and nothing more. If you want your file names in your dataframe you can easily use `fileList[i]` instead of i, which gives you the full path. Afterwards you can use a grep or trim command which cuts your file path to file name. There are a lot tutorials on this site for this